# Ordering Tasks by completion time while keeping track of their index in an argument list?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, ienumerable

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776546/waiting-for-a-single-task-to-fail-out-of-a-listtask-more-cleanly-possibly/36776706?noredirect=1#comment61130399_36776706) about the possibility of cleaning up some code, the code was meant to wait for each `Task` in a `List<Task<T>>` to complete but cancelling all `Task` if one returned some falsey value.

A user named Servy [quickly produced a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36776706/2985796) which eloquently orders a `List<Task<T>>` by their completion time. After reading over the answer a bit I think/thought I understand/stood the method. I then went to use the method but quickly realized an issue. I need to be able to recognize the `Task`s as they are completing. But the `Order` method Servy suggested provides no means to do this (because I cannot compare the task continuations returned by `Order` to my `List<Task<>>` I supplied it originally).

So I went to change the method to return a `Tuple<T, int>` where the `int` represents the original index of the `Task` in the provided arguments.

```
public static IEnumerable<Task<Tuple<T, int>>> OrderByCompletion<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var taskList = tasks.ToList();
    var taskSources = new BlockingCollection<TaskCompletionSource<Tuple<T, int>>>();
    var taskSourceList = new List<TaskCompletionSource<Tuple<T, int>>>(taskList.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < taskList.Count; i++)
    {
        var task = taskList[i];
        var newSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Tuple<T, int>>();
        taskSources.Add(newSource);
        taskSourceList.Add(newSource);

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var source = taskSources.Take();

            if (t.IsCanceled)
                source.TrySetCanceled();
            else if (t.IsFaulted)
                source.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
            else if (t.IsCompleted)
                source.TrySetResult(new Tuple<T, int>(t.Result, i));
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    return taskSourceList.Select(tcs => tcs.Task);
}

// Usage
foreach(var task in myTaskList.OrderByCompletion())
    Tuple<Boolean, int> result = await task;
```

The issue I am facing is that index inside of the `Tuple` returned seems to always be equal to the `Count` of the original `List<Task<>>` passed to `OrderByCompletion` no matter the order of the task returned.

I assume that as a result of this issue I do not fully understand how this method worked in the first place, though it seems to be that it should work just fine.

**Can anyone explain the issue and offer a solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are using `i` variable inside an `Action<>`.

But the code of this action is not executed when your create the `Action`, but when the task is completed, then the variable `i` has value `taskList.Count` (when `for` loop finished).

You can fix your problem simply adding an extra variable to the `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < taskList.Count; i++)
{
    var task = taskList[i];
    var newSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Tuple<T, int>>();
    taskSources.Add(newSource);
    taskSourceList.Add(newSource);

    int index = i; // <- add this variable.

    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        var source = taskSources.Take();

        if (t.IsCanceled)
            source.TrySetCanceled();
        else if (t.IsFaulted)
            source.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
        else if (t.IsCompleted)
            source.TrySetResult(new Tuple<T, int>(t.Result, index));
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

You can read this [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/271440/5178207) for more details.

Comment: Ohhhhhh yeah! I have seen this "issue" before in a blog post (I think by Eric Lippert?). This makes total sense. Thank you!