# Getting reference to original Task after ordering Tasks by completion?

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, task

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799825/ordering-tasks-by-completion-time-while-keeping-track-of-their-index-in-an-argum) a while ago about a method that orders a `List<Task<T>>>` by their completion that also returns an `int` representing the index of the completed `Task` in the original `List<Task<T>>` given.

I have the inkling that I might not need to return this `int` to determine which specific `Task` has completed and that I can interrogate the returned `Task` for this information.

---

As a side note, I have since altered the method to order a `List<Task>`. I originally used `Task<T>`, which returned a `bool` to represent if the `Task<T>` was successful in its job or not. I now simply throw a subclass of `Exception` which provides more information about how and why a `Task` failed.

My idea for this question came from the issue that when a `Task<int>` from this method throws an `Exception` I have no way to determine which specific `Task` threw the `Exception` because I cannot interrogate the `Task<int>.Result` for the `Task`'s original index.

So again, if I can interrogate the `Task<int>` (now simply just `Task`) that is returned for the `Task` it refers to from the original list, I can simply compare the references.

---

Here is the method as it now exists (Credit to Servy for the [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36776706/2985796) for this method. Also possibly this [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/01/16/eduasync-part-19-ordering-by-completion-ahead-of-time/) from Jon Skeet)

```
public static IEnumerable<Task<int>> OrderByCompletion(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    var taskList = tasks.ToList();
    var taskSources = new BlockingCollection<TaskCompletionSource<int>>();
    var taskSourceList = new List<TaskCompletionSource<int>>(taskList.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < taskList.Count; i++)
    {
        var task = taskList[i];
        var newSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        taskSources.Add(newSource);
        taskSourceList.Add(newSource);

        int index = i;

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var source = taskSources.Take();

            if (t.IsCanceled)
                source.TrySetCanceled();
            else if (t.IsFaulted)
                source.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
            else if (t.IsCompleted)
                source.TrySetResult(index);
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    return taskSourceList.Select(tcs => tcs.Task);
}
```

My first issue is that this method uses `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to track the `TResult` of the `Task` from the parameter list. Seeing as the `List<Task>>` now returns no value and uses `Exception`s this is useless, though its usage is unavoidable because there is no non generically parameterized `TaskCompletionSource<T>` *But this is not really a problem because I can just return some trash value.*

So, to the question itself, **can I interrogate the `Task<(unused return value)>` to get a reference to the `Task` it tracks?**

---

From what I can tell the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` has no information about the `Task` it is tracking. It simply "looks like" the original `Task`.

Is the only option to subclass `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to add one property that refers to the `Task` it tracked, set the value of the property in the method, and then interrogate that property for the reference?

```
public class TaskHoldingTaskCompletionSource<T> : TaskCompletionSource<T>
{
    public Task OriginalTask { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the way `WhenAny` solves this problem for its analogous operation.  Have the method return a `Task` whose result is the `Task` that it logically represents the completion of, rather than computing the same logical value as that task.  This forces the caller to unwrap that task if they just care about the task's result (or error state), but if you don't always want it unwrapped, you can just return the whole `Task`.  It actually *simplifies* the code to not have the `Order` method unwrap the task for you.

```
public static IEnumerable<Task<Task>> Order2(this IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    var taskList = tasks.ToList();

    var taskSources = new BlockingCollection<TaskCompletionSource<Task>>();

    var taskSourceList = new List<TaskCompletionSource<Task>>(taskList.Count);
    foreach (var task in taskList)
    {
        var newSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Task>();
        taskSources.Add(newSource);
        taskSourceList.Add(newSource);

        task.ContinueWith(t => taskSources.Take().TrySetResult(t),
            CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    return taskSourceList.Select(tcs => tcs.Task);
}
```

Comment: I had had the idea that instead of using the `<T>` as a trash value to return the `Task` as you have here. But the issue I saw is that if I try to interrogate the `Task<Task>.Result` and the original `Task` threw an `Exception` I wouldn't be able to get the reference to the `Task` just the `Exception` it threw. // Though I might need to think this over before I really commit to thinking that. // Actually I think I might not fully understand `TaskCompletionSource<T>` yet..

Comment: @KDecker In this code we *never* set any `Task` returned by `Order2` to faulted.  If the first `Task` to complete faults, `Order2` will return a `Task` *that successfully ran to completion* that has a `Result` holding onto the faulted `Task`.

Comment: Ohhhh I see now (I think). Wow, yet another intellectually aesthetic piece of code there. Thanks again Servy!