# Merge multiple IAsyncEnumerable streams

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, iasyncenumerable, ix.net

With the release of [Mediatr 10](https://jimmybogard.com/mediatr-10-0-released/), there's now a paradigm that allows developers to create streams powered by `IAsyncEnumerable`. I'm leveraging this paradigm to create multiple different file system watchers to monitor multiple folders. To monitor the folders, I'm leveraging two different approaches: Polling and `FileSystemWatcher`. As part of my pipeline, all of the different folder monitors are aggregated into a single `IEnumerable<IAsyncEnumerable<FileRecord>`. In each type of watcher, there's an internal loop that runs until cancellation is requested via a `CancellationToken`.

Here's the polling watcher:

```cs
public class PolledFileStreamHandler : 
    IStreamRequestHandler<PolledFileStream, FileRecord>
{
    private readonly ISeenFileStore _seenFileStore;
    private readonly IPublisher _publisher;
    private readonly ILogger<PolledFileStreamHandler> _logger;

    public PolledFileStreamHandler(
        ISeenFileStore seenFileStore, 
        IPublisher publisher, 
        ILogger<PolledFileStreamHandler> logger)
    {
        _seenFileStore = seenFileStore;
        _publisher = publisher;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<FileRecord> Handle(
        PolledFileStream request, 
        [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<FileRecord>();
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(request.Folder)
                .Where(f => !_seenFileStore.Contains(f));

            await Parallel.ForEachAsync(files, CancellationToken.None, async (f,t) =>
            {
                var info = new FileRecord(f);
                
                _seenFileStore.Add(f);
                await _publisher.Publish(new FileSeenNotification { FileInfo = info }, t);
                queue.Enqueue(info);
            });
            
            // TODO: Try mixing the above parallel task with the serving task... Might be chaos...

            while (!queue.IsEmpty)
            {
                if (queue.TryDequeue(out var result))
                    yield return result;
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("PolledFileStreamHandler watching {Directory} at: {Time}", request.Folder, DateTimeOffset.Now);
            
            await Task.Delay(request.Interval, cancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith(_ => {}, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
}
```

And the FileSystemWatcher

```cs
public class FileSystemStreamHandler : 
    IStreamRequestHandler<FileSystemStream, FileRecord>
{
    private readonly ISeenFileStore _seenFileStore;
    private readonly ILogger<FileSystemStreamHandler> _logger;
    private readonly IPublisher _publisher;
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<FileRecord> _queue;

    private Action<object, FileSystemEventArgs>? _tearDown;

    public FileSystemStreamHandler(
        ISeenFileStore seenFileStore, 
        ILogger<FileSystemStreamHandler> logger, 
        IPublisher publisher)
    {
        _seenFileStore = seenFileStore;
        _logger = logger;
        _publisher = publisher;
        _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<FileRecord>();
    }

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<FileRecord> Handle(
        FileSystemStream request, 
        [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var watcher = SetupWatcher(request.Folder, cancellationToken);
        
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (_queue.TryDequeue(out var record))
                yield return record;

            await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith(_ => {}, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        
        TearDownWatcher(watcher);
    }
    
    private FileSystemWatcher SetupWatcher(string folder, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(folder);
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                               | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                               | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                               | NotifyFilters.FileName
                               | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                               | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                               | NotifyFilters.Security
                               | NotifyFilters.Size;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        _tearDown = (_, args) => OnWatcherOnChanged(args, cancellation);
        watcher.Created += _tearDown.Invoke;

        return watcher;
    }
    
    private async void OnWatcherOnChanged(FileSystemEventArgs args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var path = args.FullPath;

        if (_seenFileStore.Contains(path)) return;
            
        _seenFileStore.Add(path);

        try
        {
            if ((File.GetAttributes(path) & FileAttributes.Directory) != 0) return;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("File {File} was not found. During a routine check. Will not be broadcast", path);
            return;
        }
            
        var record = new FileRecord(path);
        _queue.Enqueue(record);
        await _publisher.Publish(new FileSeenNotification { FileInfo = record }, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void TearDownWatcher(FileSystemWatcher watcher)
    {
        if (_tearDown != null)
            watcher.Created -= _tearDown.Invoke;
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the class that ties everything together and attempts to monitor the streams (in the `StartAsync` method). You'll notice the presence of a `Merge` operator coming from [`System.Interactive.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/), this does not currently operate as desired.

```cs
public class StreamedFolderWatcher : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<Func<IAsyncEnumerable<FileRecord>>> _streams;
    private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationTokenSource;
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    private readonly ILogger<StreamedFolderWatcher> _logger;

    public StreamedFolderWatcher(
        IMediator mediator,
        IEnumerable<IFileStream> fileStreams, 
        ILogger<StreamedFolderWatcher> logger)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
        _logger = logger;
        _streams = new ConcurrentBag<Func<IAsyncEnumerable<FileRecord>>>();
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        fileStreams.ToList()
            .ForEach(f => AddStream(f, _cancellationTokenSource.Token));
    }

    private void AddStream<T>(
        T request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
        where T : IStreamRequest<FileRecord>
    {
        _streams.Add(() => _mediator.CreateStream(request, cancellationToken));
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource
            .CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);

        var streams = _streams.Select(s => s()).ToList();
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await foreach (var file in streams.Merge().WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Incoming file {File}", file);
            }
            
            await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith(_ => {}, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

My expectation for the `Merge` behavior is that if I have 3 `IAsyncEnumerables`, each item should be emitted as soon as it's yielded. Instead, unless I place `yield break` somewhere within the loops, the first `IStreamRequestHandler` fetched will simply execute ad infinitum  until the cancellation token forces a stop.

How can I merge multiple input `IAsyncEnumerables` into a single long-lived output stream, that emits each time a result is yielded?

## Minimum Reproducible Sample

```cs
static async IAsyncEnumerable<(Guid Id, int Value)> CreateSequence(
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var id = Guid.NewGuid();
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(100, 1000)));
        yield return (id, random.Next(0, 10));
    }
}

var token = new CancellationTokenSource();
var sequences = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(_ => CreateSequence(token.Token));
var merged = sequences.Merge();

await foreach (var (id, value) in merged)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}] Value {value} Emitted from {id}");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronously write to an IAsyncEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70023736/asynchronously-write-to-an-iasyncenumerable)

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm not sure. That appears to be tailored towards converting `IEnumerable<Task>` to a unified `IAsyncEnumerable`, but I will see if any of it can be repurposed.

Comment: Oof.. I've seen a duplicate of this recently..

Comment: This looks like a classical usecase for the producer consumer pattern. Maybe you can enumerate all asyncenumerables into a channel and then return ReadAllAsync. Cf. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/

Comment: I have come up with a rather brute force solution that utilizes several background tasks. I will post it below. It's definitely far from the best solution, so I'll leave the question open in anticipation of being corrected.

Comment: Could you include a minimal example that reproduces the undesirable behavior of the `Merge` operator?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Please see my updated question for my repro.

Comment: It seems that the issue you are facing is fixed now (as of `System.Interactive.Async` 6.0.1). I just wanted to take a moment and say that I really appreciated this question because it helped me better understand how to work with `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` as well as this library.

[Working example](https://github.com/JaimeStill/distributed-architecture/blob/f4637b5488ab4488825c3fd6adecbf2b0ab0d0b3/proto/Picsum/PicsumPhoto.cs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the Rx team messed up with the [`Merge`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Merge.cs) operator, and have created overloads with divergent behavior. This overload supports concurrency:

```
public static IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> Merge<TSource>(
    params IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>[] sources);
```

This overload does not support concurrency:

```
public static IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> Merge<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>> sources);
```

From the comments inside the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Merge.cs#L315):

```
// REVIEW:
// This implementation does not exploit concurrency. We should not introduce such
// behavior in order to avoid breaking changes, but we could introduce a parallel
// ConcurrentMerge implementation. It is unfortunate though that the Merge
// overload accepting an array has always been concurrent, so we can't change that
// either (in order to have consistency where Merge is non-concurrent, and
// ConcurrentMerge is).
```

So what you have to do is to convert your enumerable `.ToArray()` before the `Merge()`.

Comment: Well isn't that something! That's a fantastic catch. I can confirm that this does appear to correct the issue entirely. Also worth noting, I cannot use the extension method to accomplish this, instead I have to rely on `AsyncEnumerableEx.Merge` instead of `myAsyncEnumerableCollection.Merge()`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a *working*, but likely inefficient and potentially buggy solution. By putting each `IAsyncEnumerable` into its own background task, I'm able to emit each into a thread-safe queue, where they're served up as each one comes available.

```cs
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> MergeAsyncEnumerable<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>> sources,
    TimeSpan? debounceTime = default,
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<TSource>();
    var tasks = SetupCollections(sources, queue, cancellationToken);
    
    while (!Task.WhenAll(tasks).IsCompleted)
    {
        while (!queue.IsEmpty)
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out var record))
                yield return record;
            
        // Small debounce to prevent an infinite loop from just spinning. 
        await WaitIfDebounce(debounceTime, cancellationToken);
    }

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}

private static Task WaitIfDebounce(
    TimeSpan? debounceTime,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return debounceTime.HasValue
        ? Task.Delay(debounceTime.Value, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(_ => { }, CancellationToken.None)
        : Task.CompletedTask;
}

private static IList<Task> SetupCollections<TSource>(
    IEnumerable<IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>> sources,
    ConcurrentQueue<TSource> queue,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return sources
        .Select(s => Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await foreach (var file in s.WithCancellation(cancellationToken)) 
                queue.Enqueue(file);
        }, cancellationToken))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Overall, it's unnecessary, but I added it for my particular use-case as a sort of debounce.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it also helped get the CPU usage down since I didn't just have an infinite loop sitting there spinning. On my i9-9900k, the app's CPU usage goes from a constant 6-8% down to 0-1%.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents for merging `IAsyncEnumerable` streams:

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<JobResult> Merge(List<IAsyncEnumerator<JobResult>> enumerators, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    List<(Task<bool> task, IAsyncEnumerator<JobResult> enumerator)> enumeratorsInProgress = new();
    foreach (IAsyncEnumerator<JobResult> enumerator in enumerators)
    {
        enumeratorsInProgress.Add((enumerator.MoveNextAsync().AsTask(), enumerator));
    }

    while (enumeratorsInProgress.Any())
    {
        await Task.WhenAny(enumeratorsInProgress.Select(item => item.task));

        var length = enumeratorsInProgress.Count - 1;
        for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // Check for additional TaskStatus as needed
            if (enumeratorsInProgress[i].task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                var enumeratorWithCompletedTask = enumeratorsInProgress[i];
                enumeratorsInProgress.Remove(enumeratorWithCompletedTask);
                if(enumeratorWithCompletedTask.task.Result)
                {
                    yield return enumeratorWithCompletedTask.enumerator.Current;
                    var enumeratorInProgress = (enumeratorWithCompletedTask.enumerator.MoveNextAsync().AsTask(), enumeratorWithCompletedTask.enumerator);
                    enumeratorsInProgress.Insert(enumeratorsInProgress.Count, enumeratorInProgress);
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```