Merging two IAsyncEnumerable instances with cancellation support (NotSupportedException)
I'm having trouble implementing the following properly:
I have two IAsyncEnumerable instances (of the same type), one is the "primary" source, the purpose of the other is so the user can "insert" items on demand.
So if the primary source ends, the secondary also needs to stop, ending the enumeration.
The caller of the Merge function also needs to be able to react when the primary source ends (i.e. cleanup the secondary enumerable).
Given this I came up with the following implementation:
static async IAsyncEnumerable<object?> Merge(IAsyncEnumerable<object?> primary, IAsyncEnumerable<object?> secondary, Action primaryFinished, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct) {
    var pIt = primary.GetAsyncEnumerator(ct);
    var sIt = secondary.GetAsyncEnumerator(ct);

    await using var _pIt = pIt.ConfigureAwait(false);
    await using var _sIt = sIt.ConfigureAwait(false);

    Task<bool>? pItTask = null;
    Task<bool>? sItTask = null;

    IAsyncEnumerator<object?>? it = null;
    while (true) {
        Task<bool> task;

        try {

            pItTask ??= pIt.MoveNextAsync().AsTask();
            sItTask ??= sIt.MoveNextAsync().AsTask();


            task = await Task.WhenAny(pItTask, sItTask).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (pItTask == task) {
                pItTask = null;
                it = pIt;
                if (!task.Result) {
                    primaryFinished();
                    yield break;
                }

            } else {

                sItTask = null;
                it = sIt;
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            primaryFinished();
            yield break;
        }

        if (task.Result) yield return it.Current;
    }
}

The problem is that this will throw a NotSupportedException if the primary source throws an exception, which messes up my exception handling while going up the stack.
I found a github issue which mentions the problem but doesn't really solve it (I'm getting the exception even with the delay).
Full Code to reproduce the issue:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/v7SgEV
//Needs the "System.Interactive.Async" nuget package
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Channels;

while (true) {
    try {
        using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var secondaryDataSource = Channel.CreateUnbounded<object?>();

        var reader = PrimaryDataSource(cts.Token).Do(x => {
            Console.WriteLine("---");
        });

        var combinedSource = Merge(
            reader,
            secondaryDataSource.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cts.Token),
            () => secondaryDataSource.Writer.TryComplete(),
            cts.Token
        );

        await foreach (var item in combinedSource) {
            Console.WriteLine(item ?? "<Null>");
            throw new Exception();
        }

    } catch (NotSupportedException ex) {
        throw;
    } catch (Exception) {
    }
}

static async IAsyncEnumerable<object?> PrimaryDataSource([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct) {
    while (true) {
        await Task.Delay(Random.Shared.Next(100), ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
        yield return "PrimaryDataSource";

        throw new Exception();
        yield break;
    }
}

static async IAsyncEnumerable<object?> Merge(IAsyncEnumerable<object?> primary, IAsyncEnumerable<object?> secondary, Action primaryFinished, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct) {
    var pIt = primary.GetAsyncEnumerator(ct);
    var sIt = secondary.GetAsyncEnumerator(ct);

    await using var _pIt = pIt.ConfigureAwait(false);
    await using var _sIt = sIt.ConfigureAwait(false);

    Task<bool>? pItTask = null;
    Task<bool>? sItTask = null;

    IAsyncEnumerator<object?>? it = null;
    while (true) {
        Task<bool> task;

        try {

            pItTask ??= pIt.MoveNextAsync().AsTask();
            sItTask ??= sIt.MoveNextAsync().AsTask();


            task = await Task.WhenAny(pItTask, sItTask).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (pItTask == task) {
                pItTask = null;
                it = pIt;
                if (!task.Result) {
                    primaryFinished();
                    yield break;
                }

            } else {

                sItTask = null;
                it = sIt;
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            primaryFinished();
            if (pItTask != null) await pItTask;
            if (sItTask != null) await sItTask;
            yield break;
        }

        if (task.Result) yield return it.Current;
    }
}


No, since this will return both items at the same time and it would probably wait until until both are ready to provide an item (The secondary sequence will, in most cases, never produce items).  So https://stackoverflow.com/a/70659874/275748 might be more fitting but it treats both sequences equally and I need more control.

What is the desirable behavior in case both the primary and secondary sequences have items immediately available? In this case are you OK with receiving items from the primary sequence only, or you would prefer alternating between the two sequences? See this question for a demonstration of the left-side bias behavior that I am talking about.

A bias is ok as long as items from either source aren't blocked for a long time. (The primary source will return items at a "moderate" rate, while the secondary will seldomly produce items). But the merged enumeration needs to stop once the primary source is finished, which seems is not possible with that method.

Your problem is just that you did not handle the disposal of async enumerators correctly. You'd better read the answers to Theodor Zoulias' question again.

Thanks that pointed me into the right direction. It is the DisposeAsync which throws the NotSupported Exception. Doing the "await using" manually with additional "try {} catch {}" seems to fix the issue.  TheodorZoulias/shingo If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

I think that there are simpler solutions to your problem than implementing a complex, and fundamentally broken, version of the Merge operator. Assuming that you are already using the System.Interactive.Async package, which contains a Merge operator, it also contains a Finally operator that you could use like this: var merged = primary.Finally(() => secondarySource.Complete()).Merge(secondary);

Going by the comments by TheodorZoulias/shingo I found the Problem and fixed it:
private static async IAsyncEnumerable<object?> Merge(IAsyncEnumerable<object?> primary, IAsyncEnumerable<IList<object?>> secondary, Action primaryFinished, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct) {
    var pIt = primary.GetAsyncEnumerator(ct);
    var sIt = secondary.GetAsyncEnumerator(ct);

    var _pIt = pIt.CAf();
    var _sIt = sIt.CAf();

    Task<bool>? pItTask = null;
    Task<bool>? sItTask = null;

    try {
        IAsyncEnumerator<object?>? it = null;
        while(true) {
            Task<bool> task;
            pItTask ??= pIt.MoveNextAsync(ct).AsTask();
            sItTask ??= sIt.MoveNextAsync(ct).AsTask();

            task = await Task.WhenAny(pItTask, sItTask).CAf();
            if(pItTask == task) {
                pItTask = null;
                it = pIt;
                if(!task.Result) {
                    primaryFinished();
                    yield break;
                }
            } else {
                sItTask = null;
                it = sIt;
            }

            if(task.Result) {
                yield return it.Current;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        try { await _pIt.DisposeAsync(); } catch { }
        try { await _sIt.DisposeAsync(); } catch { }
    }
}

The important parts are the try/catches around the DisposeAsyncs since they might throw.

What is the .CAf()?

Your implementation leaves the enumerator of the secondary sequence undisposed, and also it forgets the last pending MoveNextAsync operation of the secondary sequence. This is not a good behavior for general use. Fire-and-forget is frowned upon by the experts, and for very good reasons.

Also the case of the secondary sequence completing first is handled poorly. At that point the sIt.MoveNextAsync(ct) will always return a completed task, causing your implementation to enter a tight loop, burning one CPU core for no reason.
